# Getting no-return-assign lint error for filteredArray.forEach((x) => (x.order -= 1)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript-eslint

I used `filteredArray.forEach((x) => (x.order -= 1));` in order to decrement by 1 the order field for all the elements stored in filteredArray.
Now I am getting the lint error: `Arrow function should not return assignment  no-return-assign`

Answer (score 1):

you just change `()` to `{}`:

```
filteredArray.forEach((x) => {x.order -= 1});
```